# IAM Policy to allow deletion only from specific folders of a S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I have a bucket: `s3://mybucket`

I want to allow deletion only for objects under `s3://mybucket/test`

I tried the following policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1604573937792",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "test/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, the IAM policy simulator trying to delete the object `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/test/x.txt` fails saying "implicitly denied (no matching statements)". What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3 - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html), you'll notice that `DeleteObject` does not accept a `Prefix`.

Instead, you can use:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/text/*"
        }
    ]
}
```